# Trigonometry: Isosceles Triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I saw the following problem on Facebook (figure not drawn to scale):

> [image]
>
> $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with $AB\equiv BC$, $AC\equiv BD$, and $\angle B=20^\circ$. Find $\angle CAD$.

What I did was let $BC\equiv x$ and divide the triangle in two by bisecting $\angle B$. This yielded two right triangles with base $x\cos80^\circ$. Therefore, the base of $\triangle ABC$ has length $2x\cos80^\circ$.

Clearly, $DC=x-2x\cos80^\circ$, and $\angle C=80^\circ$.

Now, to find $AD\equiv y$, I used the law of cosines:

$$
y=\sqrt{(2x\cos80^\circ)^2+(x-2x\cos80^\circ)^2-2(2x\cos80^\circ)(x-2x\cos80^\circ)\cos80^\circ}.
$$

Finally, to find $\angle CAD\equiv\theta$, I used the law of sines:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin80^\circ}{y}&=\frac{\sin\theta}{x-2x\cos80^\circ}\\
\Longrightarrow\theta&=70^\circ.
\end{align}$$

Is my result correct? Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: While using trigonometry does give an answer, these kind of question usually requires an answer using geometry only. See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToLong.shtml

Comment: I see. Thank you for the link!

Comment: For example, construct $E$ in the triangle such that $ACE$ is equilateral. Then $BE$ bisects angle $B$ and triangle $DBA$ is congruent to triangle $ECB$. Thus $\angle{CAD}=80^{\circ}-\angle{BAD}=80^{\circ}-\angle{CBE}=80^{\circ}- \frac{\angle{CBA}}{2}=70^{\circ}$

Comment: @peterwhy Interestingly enough, all seven solutions at the link you gave are different from the one I came up with.